# Aggregate data in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data in a file like :

```
2005, 08, 20, 50
2005, 08, 21, 52
2005, 08, 22, 38
2005, 08, 23, 70
```

Data is : Year, Month, Date, temperature.

I want to read this data and output data year and month wise temperatures.
example : 2015-08: 38, 50, 52, 70.
temperature is sorted in ascending order.

What should be the spark scala code for the same? Answer in RDD transformations would appreciate a lot.
Until now I have done this so far :

```
val conf= new SparkConf().setAppName("demo").setMaster("local[*]")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val input = spark.textFile("src/main/resources/someFile.txt")
    val fields = input.flatMap(_.split(","))
```

What I am thinking is, to have year-month as a key and then list of temperatures as values. But I am not able to get this into the code.

Comment: In a DF, RDD or DS?

Comment: I wanted answer in rdd.

Comment: Unclear when you read your post: AGG, List ...

Comment: See answer, you need no flatmap!

Comment: pls comment on answers as to being helpful or not

Answer (score 1):

```
val myData = sc.parallelize(Array((2005, 8, 20, 50), (2005, 8, 21, 52), (2005, 8, 22, 38), (2005, 8, 23, 70)))
myData.sortBy(_._4).collect
```

returns:

```
res1: Array[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = Array((2005,8,22,38), (2005,8,20,50), (2005,8,21,52), (2005,8,23,70))
```

Leave you to do the concat function

Answer (score 1):

From file

```
 val filesRDD = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/Weather2.txt",1) 
 val linesRDD = filesRDD.map(line => (line.trim.split(","))).map(entries=>(entries(0).toInt,entries(1).toInt,entries(2).toInt,entries(3).toInt)) 
 linesRDD.sortBy(_._4).collect
```

returns:

```
res13: Array[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = Array((2005,7,22,7), (2005,7,15,10), (2005,8,22,38), (2005,8,20,50), (2005,7,19,50), (2005,8,21,52), (2005,7,21,52), (2005,8,23,70))
```

You can think of the concat yourself, and, what if sort values are common? Multiple sorts, but this I think answers your first less well-formed question.